# List in python will only return the first line

Tags: python

I have two lists in separate text files, "messages" and "codes". My program will open them and read them. My program is a code redeemer that will take a code and redeem it for a message.

```
lstCodes = open("codes.txt").readlines()
lstMessages = open("messages.txt").readlines()
```

I take in a user input as the code with the following class.

```
class DateCheck:
    def __init__(self, date1):
        self.date1 = date1
        if date1 == datetime.date(xxxx,x,xx):
            print('Correct! \n')
            checkx = input('Are you ready to type in your final secret code? YES = 1, NO = 0: \n')
            dcodex = input("Enter Code: \n")
            #progressB=progress(50,.04)
            LoopCheck(checkx, dcodex)
        else:
            print('Wrong code')
```

Once it asks for the user to input the code it passes it to another class that will look for that code in the text file and if found return the message from messages.txt.

```
class LoopCheck:
    def __init__(self, check, code):
        self.check = check
        self.code = code
        if code in lstCodes:
            print(lstMessages[lstCodes.index(code)])
        else:
            print("Wrong Code")
```

And heres the issue, it will only work with the first code in code.txt and the first message in message.txt. When I input the correct code2 it returns "Wrong". I've tried looking at how I'm reading the lists but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure it's a small mistake but I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
#messages.txt
message1
message2

#codes.txt
xxxx
xxxx
```

Comment: remove your classes. This are simple functions, so write them as functions.

Comment: why `input()` in your `__init__`? and since your class has only `_init_`  you should use closure

Comment: can we see your `lstCodes` variable?

Comment: @SteveJessop I did what you said using `print(lstCodes.index(code))` to find the `code` inside the list and the interpreter returned `ValueError: 'ykse' is not in list`

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner `lstCodes` contains a list of 4 letter codes separated by an `Enter` if that's what you mean?

Comment: @user3100115 I'm not very familiar with Python so any help with overall structure is appreciated. I'm not sure what a closure is?

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to use a dictionary:

```
codes = {}
with open("codes.txt") as cod_fobj, open("messages.txt") as mess_fobj:
    for code, mess in zip(cod_fobj, mess_fobj):
        codes[code.strip()] = mess.strip()
```

Now:

```
>>>> codes['code1']
'message1'
```

The check could look like this:

```
if code in codes:
    print(codes[code])
else:
    print("Wrong Code")
```

Or:

```
try:
    print(codes[code])
except KeyError:
    print("Wrong Code")
```

Comment: I figured out how to do it but I will give this a try also. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what was wrong. I changed the formatting on `codes.txt` to:

```
#codes.txt
xxxx, xxxx, xxxx
```

I also changed `lstCodes = open("codes.txt").readlines()` to `lstCodes = open("codes.txt").read().split(',')`so now when I look for the code in `code.txt` it returns its index and then I look up the index number on `messages.txt` and return the message associated with it.